# How to insert data into mysql using python and UDP

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, udp

I am trying to insert some data into mysql sent from UDP client to UDP server.
So far, I've checked that the UDP server I created receives data sent from client. I am struggling to store the data into a database in MySQL.
It shows it prints out "checking" but not "running" So I am assuming
there's something wrong with the location of 'mydb = mysql.connector.connect()' part.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector
import socket
print("checking")
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port="8888",
        user="root",
        password="000000",
        auth_plugin="mysql_native_password",
        database="final"
)

print("running")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8888))
while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    data = data.decode().upper()
    sock.sendto(data.encode(), addr)
    print('receive {} bytes from {}.'.format(len(data), addr))
    print(data)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO final (name) VALUES (%s)"
    val = (data)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()

    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

sock.close()
```

Comment: So how (what language) did you create a UDP Server in?

Comment: sorry i did it in python.